# Cannot read properties of undefined (Sentry Next.js Wizard)

Tags: next.js, sentry

I am using `"next": "13.2.4"` and trying to install Sentry for Next.js [using wizard](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/):

```
npx @sentry/wizard@latest -i nextjs
```

But I always get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

[image]

Anyone experienced this issue and fixed this? Pls advice.

Answer (score 2):

After creating new project in Sentry (sentry.io/projects/) and try again, worked fined.